# Removing/Overriding Constructor Statements (PHP)

Tags: php, constructor

I learned that I can use a parent's constructor in PHP with `ParentClass::__construct();`.
I imagine it's not possible, but I want to be sure; can I override or remove an aspect of the copied constructor? In other words, if the parent's constructor was

```
public function __construct(){
  print "This is from the parent class";
  test();
}

public function test(){
  print "Remove this function when copying to child class";
}
```

is there any way that I can

```
public function __construct(){
  ParentClass::__construct();
  //override/remove/negate test() function in the copied construct.
}
```

Comment: Should be `parent::__construct` (your way also works, I believe, but isn't common/recommended). Also, what do you mean "override/remove/negate"? What should calling that method on a child object do?

Comment: If I write out `parent::__construct()` in the child class, that means the child's class will be the parent's constructor plus whatever else the child's constructor has as well, right?
I want to know if there's anything I can add to the child's constructor to remove or override the `test` function it now carries.
In other words, in the child's constructor I want `parent::__construct()`, minus the `test();`

Comment: That statement will simply call the parent constructor (so execute all the statements within it). So yes, if `parent::construct()` is the first line of the child constructor, the result is what you've just described.

Comment: Ok, but I can do what I mentioned at the end of my reply?

Comment: There is no relationship between the constructor and the `test` method (well, other than you need an instanciated object to call a method). Do you want objects of class `ChildClass` to not have access to the `test` method? If that is the case, you should probably not have that method in the parent class to begin with. In other words, your object structure is not right for the job.

Comment: Wrong approach. If a command in parent constructor is not meant to be in all children, it should be removed from the parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, your object structure is like this:

```
class ParentClass {
  public function test(): void {}
}

class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
  // This class has access to test() through inheritance
}
```

What you could have instead:

```
class BaseClass { 
  // Here, have everything that's actually common between all subclasses
}

class ClassA extends BaseClass {
  public function test(): void {}
}

class ClassB extends BaseClass {
  // This class does not have access to test()
}
```

You could also mix in some interfaces, but that's the basic idea.